# Is there a R function to update the my Flexdashboard on a real time basis. That is I should not run my Rmd code everyday

Tags: r, flexdashboard

I have a dataset stored in my directory in excel. It gets updates every second. I have a below rmd code written to read my excel file every second. But here only time is changing and my other function is not changing. For the reference basically my dataset is like below (Col B gets changes every second)

```
 data1 <-
    A   B
    d   3
   fd   4
   fd   5
```

Rmd code I have written below

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: fill
    runtime: shiny
---

    ```{r setup, include=FALSE}
    library(flexdashboard)
    ```
    Column {data-width=650}
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------
    ### Chart A

     ```{r}
     verbatimTextOutput("time")
     output$time <- renderPrint({
    invalidateLater(1000)
    Sys.time()
    })
    ```
    Column {data-width=350}
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------
    ### Chart B
    ```{r}
    verbatimTextOutput("sum1")
    data1 <- reactiveFileReader(intervalMillis = 5000,session = session,filePath = "E:/Anal/R 
    Programming/Flex/file1.xlsx") 
    output$sum1 <- renderPrint({
     sum(data1$B)
     })
     ```
````

Comment: Hi Folks wanted to check if you had got a chance to look at my question :)

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the brackets, it should be:

```
output$sum1 <- renderPrint({
   sum(data1()$B)
})
```

Please see also https://community.rstudio.com/t/is-there-a-r-function-to-update-my-flexdashboard-in-real-time-without-rerunning-the-rmd/40725